# Help identify ship in Star Wars: Rise of Skywalker

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

In Star Wars: Rise of Skywalker, there was a space ship that was fairly long and had red lights coming from the rear that looked like bars angled in like so:

```
/   \
```

This ship really stood out in the space scenes because it also produced a black smoke (which I found odd). I believe it was an imperial craft and possibly the ship that the Knights of Ren rode on. What is the name of this ship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*: the ship is named the [Night Buzzard](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Buzzard).

> The Night Buzzard was a modified Oubliette-class Transport used by the Knights of Ren during the First Order–Resistance war.
>
> The Buzzard was originally a dungeon ship on Osseriton, a penal world in the Unknown Regions. The vessel was liberated by the Knights during a raid on the planet alongside many prisoners.
>
> The Knights made several alterations to the Night Buzzard to better suit their tastes, such as altering the vessel's appearance to match their dark side aesthetic. The vessel's engines were also crudely modified to generate more thrust, although this took a toll on the insulation baffles, causing the Buzzard to spew noxious gas as it flew.

A popular Star Wars YouTube channel also published this information yesterday based on the Visual Dictionary:
[The Knights of Ren - Everything We Know So Far](https://youtu.be/dyzV4zsNeYc?t=3m12s)

Comment: Hello! I upvoted you because I think you have a potential answer considering Wookiepeedia says it also appears in TROS, but if you could go to the page and copy and past some of the information about it and add it to your answer, it will save your answer from being deleted, as link answers alone are not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The Knights' of Ren ship is as yet, un-named on any official source.

Sources:

[Starwars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank)

[Wookiepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren)

Comment: Give it a month and there will be a lego set of this ship and it will need a name...